# Automate rules engine on Azure Premium Verizon CDN

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-powershell, azure-cdn, infrastructure-as-code

I'm trying to automate CDN profile and endpoints using Terraform/Powershell/CLI/ARM. I can create CDN profile, endpoints etc but can't find a way to automate adding policy to rules engine.

Is there anyway to do it programmatically ?

Comment: Did you refer this  ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-manage-powershell#creating-standard-rules-engine-policy-and-applying-to-an-existing-cdn-endpoint

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-cdn-with-ruleseengine-rewriteandredirect) is an ARM template that configures rules engine device-based path rewrite and request scheme-based redirect. It's using the default Standard Microsoft CDN price tier. You can reference it and configure the rules engine on Azure Premium Verizon CDN. If it fails, I am afraid that currently there is no obvious method to configure the rule engine on Azure Premium Verizon CDN.

[Here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/42603) is an open issue about ARM template examples for the rules engine.